# Unable to jump using GDB

Tags: rhel, gdb

I'm generally successful using GDB to debug some code - although this is the first project I've ever actually use it in anger - but one particular executable is causing me problems. It's spawned as a separate process and I want to debug the first few lines so I've added a loop so that I can attach GDB to the process at leisure, then jump to the next line.  The problem is, it jumps a lot further than the next line.  I'm sure the code and the source are in sync as the addition of the loop is both visible at source level and is what occurs (ie the app "hangs" and the cpu is pegged at 100%). The app seems well behaved when not being debugged (and when the initial loop is removed).  How can I start to diagnose this problem?  It's the latest version of GDB and I'm debugging c++ exes.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than forcing the process to jump, why not write the loop as

```
int     loopflag = 0;

while (loopflag == 0)
        sleep(1);
```

and then use `gdb` to set `loopflag` non-zero?